# UIView in UIAlert

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

I want to show `UIView` in `UIAlert` and alert should be display in all another view and also when application running in background. Is it Possible ? if No then how can i do it?

Comment: my application is map based. When User arrive at saved location I have displayed a notification to do some work like reminder. If user Open Application that time then i want to show one reminder view. It contain two buttons. 1) Snooze and 2) Remind Me Later. If user Press snooze then timer will be start and after 15 minutes and reminder view will reopen after finish timer. but it happens only in that view only not in another view. So i want to show reminder view in whole application and background like a notification.  Thanks for your Help.

Comment: "Is it Possible ? if No then how can i do it?" - Well, if it's not possible, then you *can't* do it...

Comment: In this case you only can use UILocalNotification, n you must have to enable LocationService in plist for running the app in the background mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app goes in background  you dont have that much access in showing `UIAlertView`, you can try `UILocalNotification`.

But I guess you want a custom popup which is your own view.

just try creating a `UIView` and set properties from `Interface Builder`. and add as a subview.

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 290, 290)];
[self.view addSubView:v];
```

but once your app is in background, you can't do anything anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Code :-**

In view didload Method :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    flag=YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

In viewWillAppear Method :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    v=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 300)];
    v1.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    v1.clipsToBounds = YES;
    v1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 108);
}
```

And

```
-(IBAction)btn_Clicked
{

    if (flag == NO)
    {
        v=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 300)];
        v1.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
        v1.clipsToBounds = YES;
        v1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 108);

        v.hidden=NO;
        v.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        v.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2];
        [self.view addSubview:v];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        v1.frame=CGRectMake(69, 176, 185, 108);
        [v addSubview:v1];

        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
    else
    {
        v.hidden=NO;
        v.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        v.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2];
        [self.view addSubview:v];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        //v1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.3];
        v1.frame=CGRectMake(69, 176, 185, 108);
        [v addSubview:v1];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

And

```
-(IBAction)cancel_Clicked
{
    flag=NO;
    v.hidden=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UIView in UIAlertView,
but application running in background  you can't, it 's only the  notification style.